# Mootools 1.3.1: using fx.morph not working?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, mootools

I am using Mootools 1.3.1 and I want to animate a div with fx.morph but in the browser debug console I get

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'c' [null] is not an object.#
mootools-core-1.3.1.js:394
```

I built not the mootools script but I have to add some more animations and functions with mootools using this version.

My script looks like this:

```
var myEffect = new Fx.Morph("div.tile", {
duration: 'short',
transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
});

myEffect.start({
'height': 100, // Morphs the height from the current to 100px.
'width': 300   // Morphs the width from the current to 300px.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the doc:
http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Morph

the first parameter for the morph method is an "element" (object) or the id of the element, you're passing a selector.. so "div.tile" wont work.

you'll need to add an id to your element or use the `each()` method to give the effect to all the elements with the class "tile"

Test example: http://jsfiddle.net/AGVwh/ (tested on Mootools 1.2.5 and 1.3.2, so it should also work on 1.3.1)

Hope this helps

Comment: Also, passing the selector to `$$()`, i.e. `new Fx.Morph($$("div.tile"), ...)`, should fix the problem without having to add an `id` attribute to the element.

Comment: well thanks, helped me a lot. but jquerys selecter engine is much better  the documentation of mootools is so unusable =(  can i also animate z-index and can i select #id img?

Comment: +1 for spotting this. OP: actually, the selector mootools uses is W3C CSS-level3 + extras (reverse combinators). there is no need for mootools to copy the documentation over, unless it differs to expected standard. also, you should look up `el.set("morph")` and `el.get("morph")` and `el.morph({someobj})`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi hmm actually nop.. it wont work if you pass an array of elements http://jsfiddle.net/AGVwh/1/, you need the each method if you want to aply the morph to multiple elements

Comment: thanks  but something like $$("id img").morph() seems to be not working here in my script? =(

Comment: @pleasedontbelong, ah, I stand corrected then. I was under the impression that `$$()` only returned one element, silly me :)